# Facebook timeline max aspect ratio before centre crop

Tags: images, sharing, facebook, facebook-timeline

We have [this page](http://theparentingplace.automatem.co.nz/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36), which includes a hidden image, at line 856 of the source code in format 726px x 226px.

```
<img style="margin: 0px;" class="facebook" alt="toolbox" src="/images/stories/media/Facebook/toolbox.jpg" height="38" width="100" />
```

When we press the share button below, we get
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php, which shows the image fine.

[image: Not Cropped]

This is setup with Facebook meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Parents Inc." />
<meta property="og:type" content="non_profit" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://theparentingplace.automatem.co.nz//images/stories/media/Facebook/toolbox.jpg" />
```

In a "classic" Facebook profile, the image looks fine as well. However, when you switch the Facebook profile to timeline view, a centre crop is applied, cutting out the right and left side of the image.

[image: Cropped image]

The only documentation on Facebook share images I can find says the maximum aspect ratio is 1:3—this must have changed for Timeline. What is the new maximum aspect ratio?

Comment: Are you referring to the cover photo? The dimensions are 850px x 315px.

Comment: Hi, no, have updated the question, the image in question is in line 856 of the source code and outline in the meta property="og:image"

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you are seeing in the timeline, I'm a wee bit lost still.

Comment: @phwd - have updated with screenshots. When no image is specified Facebook documentation specifies an image ratio of up to 3:1 for landscape images. I'm looking for that limit for the new Facebook timeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer mentioned information at [Facebook Share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/):

> The **`og:image`** is the URL to the image that appears in the Feed story. The thumbnail's width AND height must be at least 50 pixels, and cannot exceed 130x110 pixels. The ratio of both height divided by width and width divided by height (w/h, h/w) cannot exceed 3.0. For example, an image of 126x39 pixels will not be displayed, as the ratio of width divided by height is greater than 3.0 (126/39 = 3.23). Images will be resized proportionally.

Refer some related bugs posted on [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs):

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292680607448965
- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/236831803064130

[Timeline Information](https://www.facebook.com/help/timeline)

Comment: Hehe, that was an easy bounty for us not thinking properly, indeed our image is 3.2:1 aspect ratio!